# WordPress Installation Within CakePHP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I am new to stackoverflow.

I have already installed a WordPress blog(WordPress version 3.9.2) within a CakePHP(CakePHP 1.3) site.

I have followed this link:

> http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-redirect-appwebrootblog-into-blog-wordpress-cakephp/

Changed both the `.htaccess` files as mentioned in the link.

Its working perfectly.

But the problem is if I write the url like: `www.mydomain.com/blog/` then its working perfectly

But if I write `www.mydomain.com/blog`, that means without a `/` at the end, it is still redirecting to `www.mydomain.com/app/webroot/blog/`.

Can anyone solve this out? Do I need to make any more changes to that .htaccess files?

The tutorial on that link says that if I wont write that `/` at the end it will be redirected to the proper url without any problem, but still its not working.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a caching issue?

Comment: Have you tried using CakePHP's Routing?